# How to determine whether a variable is a nngraph.Node in Lua(Torch7)

Tags: lua, torch

Suppose there is a variable named `a`, 
the output of `print(a)` is `nngraph.Node`  (this is from torch7 package)
and 
the output of `print(type(a))` is `table`

How can I use an `if` to determine whether a variable is an `nngraph.Node`

The statement

```
if a== nngraph.Node then
```

or

```
if a== "nngraph.Node" then
```

are both NOT correct!

Comment: did you try `torch.type(a)` instead of `type(a)`?

Comment: torch.type(a) still output 'table'